# carrierwave file storage saved in public directory but rails does not recognize path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

A carrierwave uploader in a Rails 6.1 application defines

```
storage :file
def store_dir
  "archive/#{model.id}"
end
```

`development.rb` does define

```
  config.active_storage.service = :local
```

The file and versions are properly process and saved to the `archive` directory.
However, when calling

```
attachment.image_url(:preview).to_s
```

the link is created, but clicking on it returns a rails routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/archive/3/PHOTO-2021-10-02-17-29-15.jpg"
```

Calling the path of the image in the browser window returns the same error.
the same occurs with `/public/archive[...]` and image tags return broken links.

While it is understandably that rails might be oriented towards an image tag expecting the file in the `assets/images` directory - the application still writes the html tag as

```
<img src="/archive/3/preview_PHOTO-2021-10-02-17-29-15.jpg" />
```

**and** the full URL does not fish out something in the public folder, returning the no route error.

*of note*  the application serves as expected the images when running under localhost.  The difference in behaviour is concerning.

two avenues of solution, thus questions:
a) how can Carrierwave be directed to saving in the `assets/images` directory
b) How can this link be properly generated and served with the full URL from the application's **public** directory

Comment: You say you are using CarrierWave but also shared an ActiveStorage configuration, I'd remove that part from the question if you are not using ActiveStorage. You don't want carrierwave to upload images in /assets/images, images should be in `/public`. You show a src `dochive`, is that a typo? you say the app serves images as expected in localhost but you never mention running the app in a different environment, are you running the app in 2 different ways? something like `/archive/3/....` will indeed look for a file at `public/archive/3/....`, you never see the `public` in the url

Comment: yes, typo.  Posted an answer to illustrate the necessity to symlink a Carrierwave local store_dir.

Answer (score 0):

This question merits an answer as it may be useful for other users.

Carrierwave and ActiveStorage do seem to be able to co-exist together, though I am not certain how as I did not document every step taken (& I wanted to test this hypothesis to a positive conclusion).

A sort of garden path was created via the `No route matches` error message.

The `public` directory used by carrierwave was being generated on every release of the application. Thus deployments would get new `public` directories, but not point to the proper one for items loaded before that deploy.  Symlink required.

Solution is to edit `deploy.rb`, in this case:

```
append :linked_dirs, 'public/archive'
```

note: this should be **only** for the carrierwave defined `store_dir`